# how to scrape popups on the website with scrapy

Tags: xpath, scrapy

I want to scrape the name, age and gender of the reviews on boots.com. For age and gender you can only see this data once you hover the mouse on the name in each review. First of all my I made the code for scraping the name but its not working. Second of all I don't know how to scrape age and gender from the pop up. Could you help me please. Thanks in advance.

Link:https://www.boots.com/clearasil-ultra-rapid-action-treatment-cream-25ml-10084703

[Screenshot of popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MEKAW.png)

```
import scrapy
from ..items import BootsItem
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader



class bootsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'boots'
    start_urls = ['https://www.boots.com/clearasil-ultra-rapid-action-treatment-cream-25ml-10084703']
    allowed_domains = ["boots.com"]


    def parse(self, response):
    reviews = response.xpath("//div[@class='bv-content-item-avatar-offset bv-content-item-avatar-offset-off']")
    for review in reviews:
        loader = ItemLoader(item=BootsItem(), selector=review, response=response)
        loader.add_xpath("name", ".//div[@class='bv-content-reference-data bv-content-author-name']/span/text()")
        yield loader.load_item()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Javascript` is used to display the data (`78` reviews in your case). You should use `Selenium` to scrape this. To display all the comments, you'll have to click multiple times on the following button :

```
//button[contains(@class,"load-more")]
```

Then, to scrape the name of all consumers you can use the following XPath (then use `.text` method to extract the data) :

```
//li//div[@class="bv-content-header-meta"][./span[@class="bv-content-rating bv-rating-ratio"]]//span[@class="bv-author"]/*/span
```

Output : `78` nodes

If you want to scrape the text reviews you can use :

```
//li//div[@class="bv-content-header-meta"][./span[@class="bv-content-rating bv-rating-ratio"]]/following::p[1]
```

Output : `78` nodes

To get the age and the gender of each consumer, you'll have to mouse over their names (see the preceding XPath) then fetch the value with the following XPath :

```
//span[@class="bv-author-userinfo-value"][preceding-sibling::span[@class="bv-author-userinfo-data"][.="Age"]]
//span[@class="bv-author-userinfo-value"][preceding-sibling::span[@class="bv-author-userinfo-data"][.="Gender"]]
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to/can't use `Selenium`, you can download the `JSON` (see the `XHR` requests in your browser) which contains everything you need.

```
https://api.bazaarvoice.com/data/batch.json?passkey=324y3dv5t1xqv8kal1wzrvxig&apiversion=5.5&displaycode=2111-en_gb&resource.q0=reviews&filter.q0=isratingsonly:eq:false&filter.q0=productid:eq:868029&filter.q0=contentlocale:eq:en_EU,en_GB,en_IE,en_US,en_CA&sort.q0=submissiontime:desc&stats.q0=reviews&filteredstats.q0=reviews&include.q0=authors,products,comments&filter_reviews.q0=contentlocale:eq:en_EU,en_GB,en_IE,en_US,en_CA&filter_reviewcomments.q0=contentlocale:eq:en_EU,en_GB,en_IE,en_US,en_CA&filter_comments.q0=contentlocale:eq:en_EU,en_GB,en_IE,en_US,en_CA&limit.q0=100&offset.q0=0&limit_comments.q0=3&callback=bv_1111_50671
```

For this case, I set the `&limit.q0=` to 100 and `offset.q0` to 0 to be sure to fetch all the data. Once you get the JSON, you'll find all the information in : `Batched Results>q0>Results>0,1,2,3,...,78`

Output :

[image: GenderAge]
To download the `JSON` use`request` and extract the data with `json` module.

Comment: Thank you so much ! will try use Selenium  :)